# jVectorMap label is not visible, why?

Tags: jquery, jvectormap

I created a slider panel with a trigger on a webpage.
On this panel I placed the jVectorMap. 
It works fine (the map is visible when I open the slider panel) just the Country labels are not visible. 
Anybody knows why?

Code parts:

```
        $(".trigger").click(function(){
                $(".panel").toggle("fast");
                $(this).toggleClass("active");
                return false;
    });


        colors = {};
        colors['it'] = '#76ced9';
        $('#map').vectorMap({
            map: 'europe_en',
            //map: 'jquery-jvectormap-europe-en',
            onLabelShow: function(event, label, code){
                if (code == 'it') {
                    event.preventDefault();
                } else if (code == 'it') {
                    label.text('bla bla bal');
                }
            },              

            colors: colors,
            hoverOpacity: 0.7, // opacity for :hover
            hoverColor: false
        });
```

Here is how the panel is created(I removed some parts to so you can see the code):

```
<div class="panel" style="z-index:10;">
    <h3>Our Destinations</h3>
    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 550px;"></div>
```

```
<a class="trigger" href="#">Map</a>
```

I was thinking that maybe since the panel is over the html it is possible that the label is not visible because it is behind but I could not figure out where to put the z-index:10;
But it is possible that the problem is something else.
If you have a sharp eye and mind you might give me a great suggestion.
Thanx,
K

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you by any chance lose the jquery.vector-map.css stylesheet in the process?  This would cause the labels and zoom buttons to disappear.

Comment: thank you for your answer! No I have the zoom buttons and they work perfectly. <pre><code><link href="<?=INST_URI;?>plugins/jquery.vector-map/jquery.vector-map.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="<?=INST_URI;?>plugins/jquery.vector-map/jquery.vector-map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?=INST_URI;?>plugins/jquery.vector-map/europe-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script></code></pre>
'

Comment: Maybe if this map is on top of a slide panel the label is not visible becouse it is in a lower layer? If yes what can I do?

Answer (score 16):

you can set `z-index=11` in *jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css* as follows:

```
.jvectormap-label {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    border: solid 1px #CDCDCD;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #292929;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif, Verdana;
    font-size: smaller;
    padding: 3px;
    z-index:11;
 }
```

Comment: the class is `.jvectormap-tip` in 2.0.1 version

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with a combination of slider and jvectormap. But instead of changing  the z-index of .jvectormap-label, I had to change the z-index of .jvectormap-tip.