# JVectorMap tooltip, label

Tags: jquery, css, jvectormap

Does anyone know how to style the tooltip/label in JVectorMap http://jvectormap.com/? I can't inspect it with the firebug. I need to add z-index as it appears under the map. Also is there a way to have the markers tooltip showing the whole time instead only on hover?
Thanks,

Comment: found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664969/jvectormap-label-is-not-visible-why?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see it here [jVectorMap label is not visible, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664969/jvectormap-label-is-not-visible-why?rq=1)

```
onLabelShow: function(event, label, code) {
    if (code == 'it') {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else if (code == 'it') {
        label.text('bla bla bal');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For tooltip do it in cleaner way (ReactJS):

```
onRegionTipShow={(e, el, code) => {
    el.css("z-index", 99);
}}
```